# Расчет движения колеса в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня такой вопрос. Есть сцена в Unity, в которой находиться колесо. Пользователь вводит радиус колеса, скорость его вращения(то есть обычная скорость движения объекта) и время которое оно крутиться(на самом деле просто стоит). Как можно рассчитать количество оборотов в минуту, путь который пройдет данное колесо и чтобы все это динамически выводилось(постепенно числа менялись) в метрах?

Comment: Длина окружности = 2 * Pi * Radius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дано: радиус r, линейная скорость v, время движения t.

```
1) *v* = v/(2πr), где *v* - частота (Гц, об./с), v - скорость (м/с), r - радиус (м)

2) s = vt, где s - перемещение (м), v - (линейная) скорость (м/с), t - время движения (с)

!) Если имеется в виду, что дана угловая скорость (хотя не похоже), то
v = Rw, где v - линейная скорость (м/с), R - радиус (м), w - угловая скорость (рад/с)

!!! Чтобы обороты в секунду перевести в обороты в минуту, 
    нужно количество оборотов в секунду умножить на 60.
```

Answer (score 0):

Могут прокрастся ошибки т.к. я пьяный сейчас, уж простите :)

---

> Пользователь вводит радиус колеса

Это автоматом дает нам возможность расчитать длинну окружности

C = 2 * π * r

> скорость его вращения(то есть обычная скорость движения объекта)

то есть скорость передвижение автомобиля -- v

> и время которое оно крутиться

t

> Как можно рассчитать путь который пройдет данное колесо

Длинна пути

S = v * t

> Как можно рассчитать количество оборотов в минуту

Общее коиличество оборотов за весь отрезок времени = S / C

дальше:

количество оборотов в минуту = общее количество оборотов / время в секундах * 60